# Finite group that has order not divisible by 3

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $o(G)=m$ and $m$ is not divisible by $3$ then show that for every element $x\in G$ there exists another element $y\in G$ such that $x = y^3$.

Comment: Say $x^r=1$. Then $x^{r+1}=x$, and $x^{2r+1}=x$, and one of those exponents is a multiple of 3.

Comment: This last conclusion I couldn't realize in spite of reaching this equation.

Comment: $r$ is a multiple of 3, or one less, or one more. Smallest possible $r$ can't be a multiple of 3 --- order of element divides order of group. In the other cases, ....

Comment: because we can always choose r carefully so that 2r+1 is not a multiple of 3. Can't we?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally, if $n$ is relatively prime to $m = |G|$, then there exist integers $a, b$ with $am + bn = 1$. Thus for any $x \in G$, $x = x^1 = x^{am+bn} = x^{bn}$ is an $n^\text{th}$ power in $G$.